# Realizar um update em campos agrupados no Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Eu tenho uma aplicação Node que conecta ao MongoDB, nela eu tenho um endpoint usando express que me retorna os maiores saldos agrupados por agência:

```
router.get("/private", async (_, res) => {
  try {
    const accounts = await accountsModel.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$agencia",
          maxBalance: { $max: "$balance" },
        },
      },
    ]);
    res.send(accounts);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Esse endpoint me retorna o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que eu preciso dar um update nos valores das agências (_id) todas para 99. Alguém sabe como fazer isso no MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz da seguinte forma, não sei se é a ideal ou se é possível fazer o update com agrupamento no mesmo método:

```
router.get("/private", async (_, res) => {
  try {
    const accounts = await accountsModel.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$agencia",
          maxBalance: { $max: "$balance" },
        },
      },
    ]);
    accounts.forEach(async (ag) => {
      await accountsModel.updateMany(
        { balance: ag.maxBalance },
        { $set: { agencia: 99 } },
        { new: true }
      );
    });
    const private = await accountsModel.find({ agencia: 99 });
    res.send(private);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```